# I do not know why there is so much margin between my title and description

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS grids and coding in general tbh. I am trying to make a shop page for my website and I cannot figure out why there is so much gap between my title and my description in the div with a class of   "title-container".

Thanks in advance for your help,

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1000px, auto);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  background-color: red;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
}

.product-side {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.title-container h1,
p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="product-side">
    <div class="title-container">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `minmax(200px, auto)` --> the row of the title will be 200px

Comment: Thanks, I decided to make an inside container so it gets applied to the container instead of the title.

Answer (score 2):

`grid-template-rows: minmax(200px, auto);` set's your title container to 200px height.

Remove or adjust this property.

Example below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1000px, auto);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  background-color: red;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
}

.product-side {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(60px, auto);
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.title-container h1,
p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="product-side">
    <div class="title-container">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```